# Problems with starting x11vnc on boot

Tags: xorg, upstart, vnc, automation

I'm trying to start up x11vnc on boot, **without** the need to log in, but I ran into quite a few problems and none of the guides helped.
First of all, **rc.local does not work,** as it apparently starts *before X11* started.

I can start it manually and connect to it from my tablet, but it fails to work on boot.

This is the very first time I'm doing something like this, but I'm 70% positive I've made no syntax errors.

**contents of my upstart script (/etc/init/remoteaccess.conf):**

```
description "Loads up remote access utilites"
start on (started lightdm)#not sure if this is correct

script
    /usr/local/bin/noip2 > /root/log
    echo "noip2 started"
    /usr/bin/x11vnc -bg -create -passwd "foopass" -viewpasswd "barpass" -o "/var/log/x11vnc.log" > /root/log
    echo "x11vnc started"
end script
```

After that, I logged in and checked if x11vnc and noip2 are running with *pidof*, but only noip2 was running. The script *does* run, as I could log things from it without problems, the *$PATH* also contains both commands, but I made sure they are found by using their full path.

I could also ping my PC from my tablet and SSH into it, without having to do *anything* after powering it on.

(this does mean I *could* just ssh into it and start x11vnc manually, but that is one ugly workaround)

What is the problem then? I can only imagine it is something to do with X11, but I may be wrong of course.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu?   What does your /etc/init/x11vnc.conf file (if you have one) look like?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have since installed XUbuntu and I no longer have the file ._.